# Problema no algoritmo sobre porcentagem

Tags: c, for

eu tinha que fazer esse algoritmo :

> Em 2010, uma pequena cidade brasileira tem 20.000 habitantes. A previsão
>   do IBGE é que esta cidade cresça a uma taxa de 5% ao ano. Sabendo
>   disso, faça um algoritmo que imprima na tela o ano e a população
>   prevista para a cidade em tal ano, com o ano variando de 2011 até 2030.

utilizando a estrutura `for` 
e eu fiz esse algoritmo:

```
float populacao;
int conta,taxa,total;

populacao=20.000;
taxa=1.05;
for (conta=2011;conta<=2030;conta++)
{
    total=populacao*taxa;
    populacao=total;

    printf("O ano de %d tera %f de habitantes \n",conta,populacao);
}
```

mas o resultado da populacao ta dando `20.000000`pra todos os anos,oque ta errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua taxa e total estão definidas como `int`, mas ela é um `float`. Mude isso e seu algoritmo estará funcionando perfeitamente.

```
float populacao,taxa,total;
int conta;

populacao=20.000;
taxa=1.05;
for (conta=2011;conta<=2030;conta++)
{
    total=populacao*taxa;
    populacao=total;

    printf("O ano de %d tera %f de habitantes \n",conta,populacao);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float populacao,taxa,total;
    int conta;

    populacao = 20.000;
    taxa = 0.05;
    for (conta=2011; conta<=2030; conta++)
    {
       total = populacao + (populacao * taxa);
       populacao = total;
       printf("O ano de %i tera %f de habitantes \n",conta,populacao);
    } 
    return(0);
}
```